# Reset Network tab default table sort order in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Network tab of Chrome developer tools, after clicking on a column header, thereby sorting the table by that column, how can I "unsort" the table and reinstate Chrome's default Network table order?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

- Right-click on any column header
- Select "Waterfall" -> "Start time"

Credit: https://christopherd.me/chrome-dev-tools-tip-resetting-the-network-panels-sort-order/

Comment: brrr, so ugly it is

Answer (score 19):

Right-click on any column header, **EXCEPT Waterfall** ...

[image]